# Posts modified in the last 48 hours

Tags: sql, recent-posts

I am using the code below to generate posts created in the last 48 hours.

```
  function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

**But** I also want to get the posts modified in the last 48 hours. Even if their creation date is older. Does anyone know how to do this?

I'd appreciate your help...

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with `WP_Query`:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'relation'   => 'OR',
        array(
            'column'  => 'post_date',
            'after'   => '-2 days'
        ),
        array(
            'column'  => 'post_modified',
            'after'   => '-2 days'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

More information about [`date_query` parameter of `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).

If, for some reason, you still want to alter the `WHERE` clausele, something like this should work (not tested):

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND ( post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days')) . " OR post_modified > " . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days')) . " )'";
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Also, you must note that in the post where filter, you are using `Y-m-d` date format, which doesn't include time. That can cause unexpected results; you may need to use MySQL datetime format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`.